# How can I delete a screenshot from the device through the app(Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement some solutions to delete a screenshot I took on the device, but nothing works.

The last one I tried was this:

```html
 val file = File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_2023-03-21-19-26-23-933_com.mi.android.globallauncher.jpg")
                Uri.fromFile(file)
                file.setWritable(true)
                if (file.canWrite()) {
                    file.delete()
                }
```

Comment: On Android 10+, no permission is allowed to public storage without making the user intentionally select those files